# Как обезопасить сайт при использовании WYSIWYG редактора?

Tags: php, безопасность, веб-программирование

Использую WYSIWYG редактор для редактирования статей другими пользователями, в нём можно вставлять HTML-теги... Так можно же вставить какой-нибудь вредоносный код... Как обезопасить сайт?

Comment: Фильтровать на стороне сервера обязательно. Дырявость WYSIWYG редактора к безопасности сайта не должна иметь никакого отношения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не все редакторы дают пользовательям добавлять коды и стили. К примеру

[CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

не дает пользоваться тегами как `<script>` или атрибутами `style`

имеются настройки тегов. что можно и чего нельзя.

*другой вариант*

[HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) - зашита скриптов и xss атак.

**но для самозащиты попробуйте `strip_tags($str, $allowedtags)`**

Comment: strip_tags - весьма слабенькая защита, если оставлять какие-то теги. Он не фильтрует аттрибуты. А вот с пурифайером я вас абсолютно поддерживаю. Именно он и подобные инструменты помогут спасти от проникновения вредоноса на сайт.